# What does "Donating for provisions" do?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

In the camp I can donate animals as food. If I carry an animal carcass, I can select it for donation like other items.

Donating items for money, or money directly has an obvious in-game benefit. I can select upgrades for the camp from the ledger from that money. But what is the benefit of donating for provisions?

Carrying around whole animals is quite a bit of work, and you can't just take your time and let them rot. So I'm wondering if it's worth it to go to the effort of bringing them back to camp to donate as food.

Comment: I'm also interested to know if I can skin the carcass keep the skin and donate the meat.

Comment: I'm also interested - it's a hell of a lot of work to ride out for a day, kill 1 deer and bring it back. Even more annoying is that it disappears if you die on your way back.

Answer (score 3):

I believe donating food raises moral and people are more likely to donate to the camp. You don't have to donate food and you're probably better off selling it to a butcher in a town.

Comment: It also counts as cash towards the camps funds. Presumably because Pearson can sell the animal.

Answer (score 1):

Donating for provisions adds to the supply of the camp. This is unlocked when you can start upgrading the camp otherwise it's fairly useless to do so. If you don't donate for provisions that resource has to be refilled at the ledger and be paid the resupply fee.